# Taking the derivative of the partition function describing a scalar QFT w.r.t. a constant

Tags: quantum-field-theory, simulations, partition-function

Premise: I know this question would be better suited to [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/), but since it strongly concerns QFT, I'm confident I'll find a more exhaustive answer here.

Consider a generic partition function $\mathcal{Z}$ describing a scalar QFT consisting of $n$ scalar field $\phi_i$:
$$\mathcal{Z} = \int \Pi_{i = 1}^{n} [\mathcal{D}\phi_i] \, \, e^{i\alpha\mathcal{S}_M},$$
where $\mathcal{S}_M = \mathcal{S}_M[ \{ \phi_i \}]$ is the action of the theory and $\alpha$ is a constant parameter. Wick-rotating, 
$$\mathcal{Z} = \int \Pi_{i = 1}^{n} [\mathcal{D}\phi_i] \, \, e^{-\alpha\mathcal{S}_E},$$
where $\mathcal{S}_E = \mathcal{S}_E[ \{ \phi_i \}]$ is the Euclidean version of the action.
Now to my question; is it correct to state that, exactly like partition function in statistical mechanics,
$$\langle \mathcal{S}_E \rangle = \frac{1}{\mathcal{Z}}\int \Pi_{i = 1}^{n} [\mathcal{D}\phi_i] \, \mathcal{S}_E \, e^{-\alpha\mathcal{S}_E} = - \frac{1}{\mathcal{Z}}\frac{\partial \mathcal{Z}}{\partial \alpha}= -\frac{\partial \ln \mathcal{Z}}{\partial \alpha}?$$
Since $\mathcal{S}_E$ shows no dependence on $\alpha$ this simple derivation seems correct to me, but I couldn't find addressed anywhere the problem of taking the derivative of a QFT partition function w.r.t. a constant (and not w.r.t. a function).

Just to give a little background to the question, I want to know if I can test the goodness of a scalar QFT numerical simulation, of which the sum of the partition function is analitically-known, just by measuring the mean value of the internal energy of system.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Try it out and see

Comment: @octonion Trying it out “naively” is pretty easy; but does the method of differentiating under the integral sign (used for normal integrals) still holds for functional integrals?

Comment: Numerically it is just a particularly big multidimensional ordinary integral right? No problem there. And even if we are not imagining a lattice cutoff, physicists differentiate functional integrals until proven guilty. I can't think of any case where this particular naive manipulation fails for what it's worth.